# Adding custom event listener (Hibernate) throws me org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate specified event (save-update) listener class

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss5.x

I am trying to add custom event listener for (UPDATE,INSERT) in my project. Following are my code snippets.

hibernate.cfg.xml file entries:

```
<event type="post-insert">
    <listener class="sample.org.app.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener"/>
</event>
<event type="save-update">
    <listener class="sample.org.app.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener"/>
</event>
```

and MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener implementation code snippet:

```
public class MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener implements PostInsertEventListener,
    PostUpdateEventListener, PostDeleteEventListener,
    SaveOrUpdateEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 400000L;
private MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListenerUtil util;

public MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener() {
    util = new MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListenerUtil();
    System.out.println("*************   MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener loaded **************");
}

@Override
public void onPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent event) {
    util.objectChanged("DELETE", event.getEntity());

}

@Override
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

    util.objectChanged("UPDATE", event.getEntity());

}

@Override
public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
    util.objectChanged("INSERT", event.getEntity());

}

@Override
public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
        throws HibernateException {
    util.objectChanged("SAVEORUPDATE", event.getObject());

  }
}
```

and my MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListenerUtil code:

```
public class MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListenerUtil {

MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListenerUtil(){        
}

public void objectChanged(String event, Object object) {

    if (object instanceof AbstractDomainObject && ! object.getClass().getName().startsWith("edu.wustl.common.domain.Audit")) {
        long objId = ((AbstractDomainObject) object).getId();
        System.out.println("*********** " + event + " : " + object.getClass().getName()+ ":" + objId + " , value= " + object.toString());
        insertIntoDB(event,object.getClass().getName(),objId);
    }else{
       // System.out.println("*********** " + event + " : " + object.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure whats wrong with my code. Please suggest me the changes. I am getting following error.

I am using 
Hibernate 3
Jboss- 5.1.0 GA
Java - 1.6

Error log:

```
14:02:43,092 INFO  [STDOUT] *************   MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener loaded **************
    14:02:43,104 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR 14:02:43,097 (DAOFactory) - Unable to instantiate specified event (save-update) listener class: edu.wustl.bms.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener
    org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate specified event (save-update) listener class: edu.wustl.bms.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListeners(Configuration.java:1539)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseEvent(Configuration.java:1521)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1452)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1414)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1405)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOFactory.setConfiguration(DAOFactory.java:278)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOFactory.buildSessionFactory(DAOFactory.java:195)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.parseDocument(ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.java:143)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.getDaoFactoryMap(ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.java:67)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.populateDaoFactoryMap(DAOConfigFactory.java:102)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.<init>(DAOConfigFactory.java:59)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.<clinit>(DAOConfigFactory.java:49)
        at edu.wustl.simplequery.bizlogic.QueryBizLogic.getQueryObjectNameTableNameMap(QueryBizLogic.java:129)
        at edu.wustl.simplequery.bizlogic.QueryBizLogic.initializeQueryData(QueryBizLogic.java:307)
        at edu.wustl.catissuecore.util.listener.CatissueCoreServletContextListener.initCatissueParams(CatissueCoreServletContextListener.java:127)
        at edu.wustl.catissuecore.util.listener.CatissueCoreServletContextListener.contextInitialized(CatissueCoreServletContextListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: edu.wustl.bms.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListeners(Configuration.java:1536)
        ... 84 more
    14:02:43,108 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR 14:02:43,107 (DAOFactory) - Problem while parsing hibernate configuration file.
    edu.wustl.dao.exception.DAOException: Problem while parsing hibernate configuration file.
        at edu.wustl.dao.util.DAOUtility.getDAOException(DAOUtility.java:348)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOFactory.setConfiguration(DAOFactory.java:284)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOFactory.buildSessionFactory(DAOFactory.java:195)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.parseDocument(ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.java:143)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.getDaoFactoryMap(ApplicationDAOPropertiesParser.java:67)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.populateDaoFactoryMap(DAOConfigFactory.java:102)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.<init>(DAOConfigFactory.java:59)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOConfigFactory.<clinit>(DAOConfigFactory.java:49)
        at edu.wustl.simplequery.bizlogic.QueryBizLogic.getQueryObjectNameTableNameMap(QueryBizLogic.java:129)
        at edu.wustl.simplequery.bizlogic.QueryBizLogic.initializeQueryData(QueryBizLogic.java:307)
        at edu.wustl.catissuecore.util.listener.CatissueCoreServletContextListener.initCatissueParams(CatissueCoreServletContextListener.java:127)
        at edu.wustl.catissuecore.util.listener.CatissueCoreServletContextListener.contextInitialized(CatissueCoreServletContextListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate specified event (save-update) listener class: edu.wustl.bms.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListeners(Configuration.java:1539)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseEvent(Configuration.java:1521)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1452)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1414)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1405)
        at edu.wustl.dao.daofactory.DAOFactory.setConfiguration(DAOFactory.java:278)
        ... 79 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ArraySt
    14:02:43,108 INFO  [STDOUT] oreException: edu.wustl.bms.MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListeners(Configuration.java:1536)
        ... 84 more
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED**
i think that there is problem with with your xml. From what i know there is no event type: 
`insert` (at least not in hibernate v3.3) but there are followin types (and interfaces which need to be implemented):

```
"auto-flush"- AutoFlushEventListener
"merge", MergeEventListener
"create", PersistEventListener
"create-onflush", PersistEventListener
"delete", DeleteEventListener
"dirty-check", DirtyCheckEventListener
"evict", EvictEventListener
"flush", FlushEventListener
"flush-entity", FlushEntityEventListener
"load", LoadEventListener
"load-collection", InitializeCollectionEventListener
"lock", LockEventListener
"refresh", RefreshEventListener
"replicate", ReplicateEventListener
"save-update", SaveOrUpdateEventListener
"save", SaveOrUpdateEventListener
"update", SaveOrUpdateEventListener
"pre-load", PreLoadEventListener
"pre-update", PreUpdateEventListener
"pre-delete", PreDeleteEventListener
"pre-insert", PreInsertEventListener
"pre-collection-recreate", PreCollectionRecreateEventListener
"pre-collection-remove", PreCollectionRemoveEventListener
"pre-collection-update", PreCollectionUpdateEventListener
"post-load", PostLoadEventListener
"post-update", PostUpdateEventListener
"post-delete", PostDeleteEventListener
"post-insert", PostInsertEventListener
"post-commit-update", PostUpdateEventListener
"post-commit-delete", PostDeleteEventListener
"post-commit-insert", PostInsertEventListener
"post-collection-recreate", PostCollectionRecreateEventListener
"post-collection-remove", PostCollectionRemoveEventListener
"post-collection-update", PostCollectionUpdateEventListener
```

So what I think you should use "post-insert" since this type requeires your listener to implements PostInsertEventListener(the one you implemented)

**OLD**
I see that the root cause of this exception you receive is java.lang.ArrayStoreException, and as javadoc states, it is

> thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong
>   type of object into an array of objects.  For example, the following
>   code generates an ArrayStoreException:
>
> ```
>     Object x[] = new String[3];
>     x[0] = new Integer(0);
> ```

please provide source of MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. I have added code for MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener in question.

Comment: oh yes. I update the xml and tested with it. I see the same error. I got some other listeners defined in my project. If I remove failing listeners, application is running fine.

Comment: check if these failing listeners implement required interfaces

Comment: Yes. I have checked them. I am implementing all required interfaces.

Comment: Finally, I figured out the issue. Its because of JARs conflicts. I am actually deploying my war file in jBoss. So, my project uses different version of Hibernate and Jboss has different version. After placing my MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener jar file in main project war, its been fixed. Previously I placed MyProjectAdaptorHibEventListener jar in Jboss.  Thanks a lot Tomasz Krzyżak for your inputs.